# Tableau - Auto Archiving Historic Data

Tags: tableau-api, archive, desktop, history

I have a live data source connected to Tableau Desktop. This source overwrites as it is updated. Is there a way to automatically save off monthly data from Tableau? Preferably, save the charts I have built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options to consider if you are using Tableau Server:

- REST API Export View: If you don't need interactivity, then you can automate exporting the image using the REST API.  This is analogous to using the Worksheet -> Export -> Image feature in the front-end.  There are other export options such as PDF and CSV.  I would recommend using the [Python client library](https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/api-ref#views) over the raw [REST API](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref.htm#download_workbook_pdf), but both are valid methods to export content.
- If you need interactivity, then you will need to use an extract instead of a live data source.  With this, you can automate exporting the workbook using the REST API.  If you want a live query for normal use, then you can duplicate the workbook, covert the data source to extract, schedule the extract refresh, and download the workbook.
- Scheduled Subscription: If you don't want to code, then you can schedule emailing an image of the view and manually save the images as needed.  You could setup a dedicated shared resource mailbox and subscribe a user, typically a service account, to the schedule.  This would allow you to consolidate all the subscriptions to a dedicated mailbox for future use.
- TabCmd: If you are comfortable with [tabcmd](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/tabcmd_cmd.htm#id7cb8d032-a4ff-43da-9990-15bdfe64bcd0), you can automate exporting to CSV, Image, and PDF.

If you are only using Tableau Desktop, then the best option may be to convert the data source to an extract, [automate refreshing the extract locally with tabcmd](https://help.tableau.com/current/online/en-us/to_refresh_extract_commandline.htm), and save a copy of the workbook to a folder while renaming the file to include a YYYY_MM_DD in the name.  This will give you a fully functional copy of the workbook.